# How to change the color of underline when hover for <TextField> component in material-ui? (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am trying to create a read only field for which I am using  component from material-ui. But when I mouse hover the component the underline color changes to dark blue/black color. How can we not change the color of the underline when hovered?

```
<TextField id="username" label="Name" className={classes.nameStyle} defaultValue="SpiderMan"
    InputLabelProps={{
             shrink: true,
    }}
/>
```

### Styling

```
nameStyle: {
        "& .MuiFormLabel-root": {
            color: "black",
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: "20px",
         },
         width: 100,
},
```

Comment: You should be able to use pseudo selectors like so: '&::hover: {textDecoration: 'none'}'. Does adding that as a property on nameStyle work?

Comment: I tried 
&::hover: {
  underline: {
       color: "red",
}
}. 
It did not work.

Comment: I do not think underline is a valid css property. You would need to use textDecoration.